# Unexpected duplicate key error using @JsonTypeInfo property

Tags: json, jackson

I have a simple hierarchy of data objects, which have to be converted to JSON format. Like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "documentType")
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(TranscriptionDocument.class), @Type(ArchiveDocument.class)})
public class Document{
  private String documentType;
  //other fields, getters/setters
}

@JsonTypeName("ARCHIVE")
public class ArchiveDocument extends Document { ... }

@JsonTypeName("TRANSCRIPTIONS")
public class TranscriptionDocument extends Document { ... }
```

Upon JSON parsing I encounter errors like this one:
`Unexpected duplicate key:documentType at position 339.` , because in the generated JSON there are actually two `documentType` fields.

What should be changed to make `JsonTypeName` value appear in `documentType` field, without an error (eg replacing the other value)?

Jackson version is 2.2

Comment: This question as been answered by another guy, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32825241/2683000

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't show it, but I bet you have a getter in your `Document` class for the `documentType` property. You should annotate this getter with `@JsonIgnore` like so:

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getDocumentType() {
    return documentType;
}
```

There is an implicit `documentType` property associated with each subclass, so having the same property in the parent class causes it to be serialized twice.

Another option would be to remove the getter altogether, but I assume you might need it for some business logic, so the `@JsonIgnore` annotation might be the best option.